# Is there a cleaner way than using for loops

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to know if there are any other ways to loop and manipulate data located in separate arrays.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(2)
b = np.arange(5)
c = np.arange(5)

l1 = []
for x in a:
    l2 = []
    for y in b: 
        l3 = []
        y = x + 1  
        for z in c:
            z = x + y
            t = (x,y,z)
            l3.append(t)
        l2.append(l3)
    l1.append(l2) 
print l1
```

Comment: What exactly is the code trying to do?

Comment: Please be more specific, what do you want to do?

Comment: Im building data based on different parameters then plotting them.  the arrays are those parameters.

Comment: Is there a different way to access them than using nested for loops?

Comment: You never use the values in `b` or `c` at all... is that intentional?  Setting `b = c = [0,0,0,0,0]` gives the same results.

Answer (score 7):

This code does exactly what you are doing.

```
def method(lst, range1, range2):
    for i in lst:
        yield [[(i, i+1, 1+(i*2))]*range2]*range1
```

Can even be turned into a generator expression:

```
def gen_method(lst, r1, r2):
    return ([[(i, i+1, 1+(i*2))]*r2]*r1 for i in lst)
```

Test it yourself if you like.

---

My tests:

```
a = range(2)
b = range(5)
c = range(5)

def your_method(a, b, c):
    l1 = []
    for x in a:
        l2 = []
        for y in b: 
            l3 = []
            y = x + 1  
            for z in c:
                z = x + y
                t = (x,y,z)
                l3.append(t)
            l2.append(l3)
        l1.append(l2)
    return l1

def my_method(lst, range1, range2):
    for i in lst:
        yield [[(i, i+1, 1+(i*2))]*range2]*range1

yours = your_method(a, b, c)
mine = list(my_method(a, len(b), len(c)))

print yours
print '==='
print mine
print '==='
print yours == mine

>>> 
[[[(0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 1)], [(0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 1)], [(0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 1)], [(0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 1)], [(0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 1)]], [[(1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3)], [(1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3)], [(1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3)], [(1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3)], [(1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3)]]]
===
[[[(0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 1)], [(0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 1)], [(0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 1)], [(0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 1)], [(0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 1)]], [[(1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3)], [(1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3)], [(1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3)], [(1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3)], [(1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3)]]]
===
True
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can compress the code using list comprehensions:

```
[[[(x,x+1,x*2 +1)]*len(c)]*len(b) for x in a]
```

What this does is loop for all x in a, and create a list of elements, where each element is a list generated for all y in b, where each element of *that* list is `(x,x+1,2*x+1)` for all z in c.

Comment: This will take a lot longer than my example, looping over the items in `c` and `b` are a waste of time, you only need their length. You can check with the timeit module.

Comment: @InbarRose: How about now?

Comment: Yes, and now it is almost like mine, but since it is not a generator expression it will take a heavier toll on the memory. It all depends on preference, I prefer generators, some prefer simple lists. Also - you do `x+x+1` and i do `1+(x*2)` which is faster.

Comment: @InbarRose: I think the OP wanted more concise/clean code, not necessarily _faster_ code :) I would have used generators, except that you had already answered with that ;-)

Comment: I sorry for the lack of specification but is is hard to explain exactly what I'm trying to do because of its complexity.  But this is helpful and I think I use the generator to create the parameters first and have just one loop instead of several nested ones.

Comment: I see a (possibly big) problem with this approach and the one of @InbarRose: [..]*len(c) makes a list of references to the same object. If you substitute the [0][0][0] element with 99, you'll see that other elements in the output list will be changed to 99. Wallace approach instead creates independent objects for each element of the list

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach is to use `itertools`, convert the resulting list to `numpy array` and reshape it

```
import numpy as np
import itertools as it

a = np.arange(2)
b = np.arange(5)
c = np.arange(5)

l1 = np.array([(i, i+1, i*2+1) for i, rb, rb in it.product(a, b, c)])
l1 = l1.reshape(len(a), len(b), len(c), len(d[0]))
```

It might be that this gets more memory consuming than all the other approaches as the size increases, but it<strike>'s only two lines and</strike> creates unique elements for each triplet instead of just creating multiple pointers to the same object.

**Edit**

An other way, that also allows to keep the triplet (i, i+1, i*1+1) as a list is:

```
l1 = np.empty([len(a), len(b), len(c)], dtype=object)
for i, rb, rb in it.product(a, b, c):
    l1[i,ra, rb] = (i, i+1, i*2+1)
```

Comment: "only two lines" the length of the code has nothing to do with efficiency, in fact, python is all about readability, in any case, one of my answers is *also* a 1 liner (inside a function call - so that is also 2 lines).... This is not faster, and not more readable.

Comment: did you downvote me just because the "only two lines"? I know that short does not mean more efficient and I wasn't trying to play at doing it shorter. I just wanted to write a short solution, without the problem that (I think) affects the other two answers.